# Getting file from resources by enum value

Tags: c#, resources

Hmmm... I have enum value (for example, 'VALUE')
and some resources with txt-files.
I'm getting this files ('MyResource_test.txt') using following code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\test.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(gui.Resources.MyResource.MyResource_test);
```

Now I need to get file from resource by my enum value

```
sw.WriteLine(gui.Resources.MyResource.VALUE);
```

How to do that? Reflection or something other?
Thanks

Comment: BTW, you can create `StreamWriter` directly from file name: `new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.txt")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ResourceManager:

```
sw.WriteLine(gui.Resources.MyResource.ResourceManager.GetString(YourEnumType.VALUE.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary that maps the enums to the resources:

```
var map = new Dictionary<YourEnumType, object>();

map[YourEnumType.VALUE] = gui.Resources.MyResource.MyResource_test;
```

Then, when you need to write it, use the map:

```
sw.WriteLine(map[YourEnumType.VALUE]);
```

If this are standard .NET resource (a .resx file), there is an alternative. These resources are accessed through generated code which access a resource by string. If you make the names of the enum values equal to the codes of the resource items, you could access them like this:

```
var item = YourEnumType.VALUE;

Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString(item.ToString());
```

Comment: That's good....but...may be there are other ways? Because in this way I will need to fill my Dictionary at first. It's similliar to using switch(enum) to get resources. May I get it without creating any other objects or using clauses?

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternative.